# Redirect Joomla 3 component url to menu associated one

Tags: php, redirect, joomla

I have this SEO issues with Joomla, that Google Webmasters Tools catches as duplicate content, titles, description...

I have an article BABOONS with id 1, and is associated with sub-category Monkeys of parent category Animals. This parent and sub category are associated to menu items.

So, normally link to this article should be www.site.com/animals/monkeys/1-baboons

And here is the problem: If you try to access to this link trough component like this:

www.site.com/component/content/article/1-baboons

link still will be valid, and it will open this article but with no itemid associated! And, as its the same title, description, keywords and content, but different URL, google says that this is duplicate content.

I have tried many components for SEF url handling, but best case scenario was returning 404.

I have tried adding rel=canonical:

```
<link href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)).'" rel="canonical" />
```

but with no luck, because it displays current url.

My question is, if there is any redirect technique or peace of code that will redirect component/content/article/1-baboons to its parent itemid /animals/monkeys/ that actually is associated with?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the built in redirect component?   It's not the ideal solution but it will work fine if it is just one. The link that you are showing is basically the permalink, guaranteed to be unique no matter what.   The question is, what is it that is leading Google's spider to that link? Usually this happens when a module or plugin is not routing a url (i.e. wrapping in JRoute()).  The core ones are generally good on this (though not unknown to find a mistake) but if you have anything that is generating links  that you have installed that is probably where the issue is.  You can look at any of the core articles modules and see what the code should look like.

Comment: No, its not just one article, you can access every article trough this way, simply add component/content/article instead of menu items path.

I have tried to find any link rendered that way, but no. All of them seems to be ok.

Comment: Of course you CAN access every article in this way, it is the permalink. But is Google finding more than one? Google will only find things that are actually linked.  For example, if there is a category link that leads to a layout that has some other link in the page that is not routed. I would start with any third party modules you have added and check the layouts of each. Also check any layout overrides.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, there is more than one permalink to access the article. I have denied in robots.txt /component/ to prevent google indexing any of that. And search in source if there is any link containing component/content/article, but with no luck. 
So, that's why i am looking for a way, to redirect path to article to menu associated one. Thanks for advice, i will continue searching in third-party extensions.

Comment: No there is only 1 permalink. Anything that depends on a menu structure is not a permalink. There can only ever be one article with id = 1.
Have you tried the redirect component that is part of the CORE of joomla?  https://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Components_Redirect_Manager BTW this is not a programming question, you should really be in the joomla SE site.    You still have not answered the question of whether google is finding a lot of these or only 1. Also of course in a dynamic system there is no "source" in the way you are thinking.